# How to make a fix size of edit field android

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I am working on android application in which i want to fix the size of the box of editfield. For example if i want to add 100 words on it, then it will not increase the size of the edit field. Characters should remains inside the box without increasing the size of edit text. I have paste the xml code of my editText along with the images.

```
                   <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/fnametxt"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.1"
                            android:background="@color/Beige"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:lines="1"
                            android:ems="15"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="ufyufgiuhjlkh"
                            android:textColor="@color/Black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
```

[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Fix your field's width.

You can do this in several ways:

1. LinearLayout with weights. Your container should have `android:weightSum="100"` (instead of 100 you can place your number). For example you can go [here](https://github.com/togramago/RunUp/blob/master/runupapp/src/main/res/layout/component_scheme_adjust_view.xml) or [here](https://github.com/togramago/RunUp/blob/master/runupapp/src/main/res/layout/activity_intro.xml). Using weights you should set `android:layout_width="0dp"` in order to see result.
2. RelativeLayout with margins. Set first EditText to `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_toRightOf="IdOfTextView"`. Set right margin to (e.g.) 10dp. EditField will be stretched in order to fill all free space.
3. You can set `android:maxWidth` to some value in dp or px. Or [maxLength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLength) or [maxEms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxEms) can do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

To Something like

```
android:layout_width="200dp"
```

or whatever size you choose.

Answer (score 0):

If your are intending to set the height using the layout_weight property set your

```
layout_height="0"
```

otherwise set

```
layout_height="100dp"
```

or whatever you want your fixed height to be.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use the XML android:maxLines and android:lines attribute and manipulate the maxLength.

```
<EditText
          android:id="@+id/fnametxt"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1.1"
          android:background="@color/Beige"
          android:enabled="false"
          android:lines="5"
          android:ems="15"
          android:maxLines="100"
          android:scrollHorizontally="true"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:text="ufyufgiuhjlkh"
          android:textColor="@color/Black"
          android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Source: [Android Developers Max Lines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines).